# Method to print primary char on even coums and the secondary char on odd columns

Tags: java

I have to create a method which will print the primary character on even columns and the secondary character on odd columns.

below is the desired output

```
. - . 
. - . 
. - . 
. - . 
. - . 
. - . 
. - .
```

Here is the method header that I have currently written:

```
public void drawPatch(int width, int height, char primary, char secondary) {

}
```

If someone could lead me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: HINT: if `col` is the column number, `col % 2 == 0` if `col` is even and `col % 2 == 1` if `col` is odd. `%` is the "modulo" operator, in case you want to research it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop in two directions (vertical and horizontal), then in the horizontal check whether current position is even or odd and print chars accordingly.

```
public static void drawPatch(int width, int height, char primary, char secondary) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            if ((i+1) % 2 == 0)
                System.out.print(primary);
            else
                System.out.print(secondary);
        }
        if (j < height - 1) { //go to next line except for last row.
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```